# WCF SOAP Service make parsing many date formats

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datetime, soap

Here is excerpt of SOAP request we use to test our service:

```
<somens:invoking_date>21.05.2012</somens:invoking_date>
```

So this is our country's local date format. Our analytics staying in USA tells us that it would be very good to support also requests with another date format. Here it is:

```
<somens:invoking_date>2012-05-21</somens:invoking_date>
```

Is it possible to tell XmlSerializer to parse any of these two date formats? Any thoughts, guys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason you have to have dates with local formats on the wire? I would stick with just one wire format, probably [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (which I think is what XmlSerializer gives you when using `DateTime` anyway), then format it for display to clients afterwards.

Comment: @Anton The issue is only the first date format is recognized by our service at the moment. We want to take at least second format, but it's better to recognize both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any built in feature here - what you could do is change this field type to be string which means you will never get exception. then in your service code do the parsing manually (or do "try parse" with various cultures)

Comment: Or the overload of [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) that lets you specify an array of permitted formats.